# How to sort pandas dataframe based on row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small pandas data frame which looks like this. Its a pandas dataframe.

```
   STUDENT_ID    RESULT
1  Roll_1_name   Steve
2  Roll_2_name   Jhon
3  Roll_3_name   Maya
4  Roll_4_name   Andy


400 Roll_1_hobby Singing
401 Roll_2_hobby Gardening
402 Roll_3_hobby Swimming
403 Roll_4_hobby Dancing


700 Roll_1_result 100
701 Roll_2_result 70
702 Roll_3_result 90
703 Roll_4_result 100
```

How to convert it like following using pandas. All should sorted like following.

```
   STUDENT_ID    RESULT
1  Roll_1_name   Steve
400 Roll_1_hobby Singing
700 Roll_1_result 100

2  Roll_2_name   Jhon
401 Roll_2_hobby Gardening
701 Roll_2_result 70


3  Roll_3_name   Maya
402 Roll_3_hobby Swimming
702 Roll_3_result 90

4  Roll_4_name   Andy
403 Roll_4_hobby Dancing
703 Roll_4_result 100
```

Comment: It looks like you could achieve this by splitting the string `STUDENT_ID` and sorting on the result afterward. What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.sort_values(by=['STUDENT_ID'])` to sort the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the number from Student_ID column, sort the dataframe with the newly created number column, and drop the sorter column.

```
(
    df.assign(number=df.STUDENT_ID.str.split("_").str[1])
    .sort_values("number")
    .drop("number", 1)
)
```